# Regenerating a Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ipa

I hope you can help me with this...

Situation: Regenerating a provisioning profile but still using the same developer certificates and app id:

- What would happen to the app using the previous provisioning profile installed to users' device when the provisioning profile is regenerated in Apple Developer Center? Would the app still behave normally or no longer run?
- If the app with the regenerated provisioning profile is being installed to a device where the app with the previous provisioning profile is already installed, would it be considered as an update or new install?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1 part - The app will behave normally. 2nd part - how do you install the app on a device? But anyway it should be considered as an update unless you change app id.

Comment: @nyekimov. we are distributing via an OTA page and airwatch.

Comment: hm haven't tried it yet. However even a certificate can be lost, so you will need to regenerate it and all provisioning profiles dependent on it and nothing will happen to older releases and they all will receive an update notification. Apple doesn't work as Android at this point.

Comment: so the basis if an app is new or an update is the app id. thank you, @nyekimov! how do i mark your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

As of questions #1, the app will work normally as long as:

- The old provision profile has not yet expired.
- The device UDID is included in the provision profile (relevant only
  for developer certificate)

As of question #2:

- As long as both apps has the same bundle ID it will be considered as
  an update.
- If both apps does not have the same Bundle ID, it will be considered
  as a new install.
- If the old app was deleted before installing the new one, it will be
  considered as a new install.

Answer (score 0):

If provisioning file is regenerated for same certificates i.e.., same bundle Id then it will be considered as an newly signed identity rather than an update. But if you revoke the certificates then the previous apps built with existing certificate will stop irrespective of provisioning files regenerated.The above situation applies only for Enterprise builds and not for Ad-Hoc builds.